# How to edit and save the connectionstring in web.config file during the installation in c#?

Tags: c#

- i have created installer for the web application.
- i want to change the default connectionstring value in web.config by the connectionstring passed by the user from the installation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way might be to simply Read in the web.config and do a string replace, then write out the web.config again:

eg: in web.config containing:

```
...
<add name="Application" connectionString="SETUP_CONNECTION_STRING" />
...
```

replace `SETUP_CONNECTION_STRING` with actual string:

This assumes its done on initial setup where multiple settings could be set without the need to use the Configuration classes etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what i need? can you tell me how to do this by code?

Comment: I wont write out ALL the code, but you can use a StreamReader to read a file to a string, do the Replace using String.Replace() and write out the file using FileStream/StreamWriter.